# Convert JavaScript String to be all lowercase

Tags: javascript, string

How can I convert a JavaScript string value to be in all lowercase letters?

Example: `"Your Name"` to `"your name"`

Comment: does a question like this *really* deserve to earn the OP 14,000 rep? That's around 130 rep per character typed (yet with no apparent attempt to solve on his own... or to Google the solution) and continues to earn the OP a title of **"Top 2% on the site"** ... even though he hasn't even logged in, for over 5 years!

Answer (score 1825, accepted):

```js
const lowerCaseName = "Your Name".toLowerCase(); // your name
```

Comment: Consider this also, "toLowerCase does not affect the value of the string str itself". This is base on a documentation here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase

Comment: what is time and space complexity of `toLowerCase()` function?

Comment: @RamzanChasygov It is both O(n) and faster than reimplementing it in JavaScript, unless you have a JavaScript engine programmed by very intelligent idiots.

Comment: A safer way to invoke `toLowerCase()` on variables would be `(varName || '').toLowerCase()`;

Answer (score 435):

Use either [toLowerCase](http://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase) or [toLocaleLowerCase](http://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLocaleLowerCase) methods of the [String](http://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/String) object. The difference is that `toLocaleLowerCase` will take current locale of the user/host into account. As per § 15.5.4.17 of the [ECMAScript Language Specification (ECMA-262)](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm), `toLocaleLowerCase`…

> …works exactly the same as toLowerCase
>   except that its result is intended to
>   yield the correct result for the host
>   environment’s current locale, rather
>   than a locale-independent result.
>   There will only be a difference in the
>   few cases (such as Turkish) where the
>   rules for that language conflict with
>   the regular Unicode case mappings.

Example:

```
var lower = 'Your Name'.toLowerCase();
```

Also note that the `toLowerCase` and `toLocaleLowerCase` functions are implemented to work generically on *any* value type. Therefore you can invoke these functions even on non-`String` objects. Doing so will imply automatic conversion to a string value prior to changing the case of each character in the resulting string value. For example, you can *apply* `toLowerCase` directly on a date like this:

```
var lower = String.prototype.toLowerCase.apply(new Date());
```

and which is effectively equivalent to:

```
var lower = new Date().toString().toLowerCase();
```

The second form is generally preferred for its simplicity and readability. On earlier versions of IE, the first had the benefit that it could work with a `null` value. The result of applying `toLowerCase` or `toLocaleLowerCase` on `null` would yield `null` (and not an error condition).

Comment: The part about `String.prototype.toLowerCase.apply(null)` returning `null` doesn't appear to be correct.  It throws a `TypeError` exception when I try it.

Comment: @JohnnyHK You're right. That bit used to hold true on earlier versions of IE where it was tested at the time the answer was originally posted. I've updated the answer to reflect your feedback. Thanks.

Answer (score 31):

Yes, any string in JavaScript has a `toLowerCase()` method that will return a new string that is the old string in all lowercase.  The old string will remain unchanged.

So, you can do something like:

```
"Foo".toLowerCase();
document.getElementById('myField').value.toLowerCase();
```

Answer (score 21):

toLocaleUpperCase() or lower case functions don't behave like they should do. For example, on my system, with Safari 4, Chrome 4 Beta, and Firefox 3.5.x, it converts strings with Turkish characters incorrectly. The browsers respond to navigator.language as "en-US", "tr", "en-US" respectively.

But there isn't any way to get user's Accept-Lang setting in the browser as far as I could find.

Only Chrome gives me trouble although I have configured every browser as tr-TR locale preferred. I think these settings only affect the HTTP header, but we can't access to these settings via JavaScript.

In the [Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/String) it says "The characters within a string are converted to ... while respecting the current locale. For most languages, this will return the same as ...". I think it's valid for Turkish, and it doesn't differ if it's configured as *en* or *tr*.

In Turkish it should convert "DİNÇ" to "dinç" and "DINÇ" to "dınç" or vice-versa.

Comment: `Accept-Language` and `navigator.language` are two completely separate settings. `Accept-Language` reflects the user's chosen preferences for what languages they want to receive in web pages (and this setting is unfortuately inaccessible to JS). `navigator.language` merely reflects which localisation of the web browser was installed, and should generally not be used for anything. Both of these values are unrelated to the system locale, which is the bit that decides what `toLocaleLowerCase()` will do; that's an OS-level setting out of scope of the browser's prefs.

Comment: I thought Accept-Language and navigator.language should be somehow related. You can configure the default language in order via browsers' settings screens, but so you can't configure what navigator.language should respond. I think there should be another form of the function toLowerCase() which gets a locale parameter.

Comment: Yeah, there should really. Unfortunately locale-related features in JavaScript are weak, poorly-specified and generally unreliable.

Answer (score 17):

Just an example for `toLowerCase()`, `toUpperCase()` and a prototype for the not yet available `toTitleCase()` or `toProperCase()`:

```js
String.prototype.toTitleCase = function() {
  return this.split(' ').map(i => i[0].toUpperCase() + i.substring(1).toLowerCase()).join(' ');
}

String.prototype.toPropperCase = function() {
  return this.toTitleCase();
}

var OriginalCase = 'Your Name';
var lowercase = OriginalCase.toLowerCase();
var upperCase = lowercase.toUpperCase();
var titleCase = upperCase.toTitleCase();

console.log('Original: ' + OriginalCase);
console.log('toLowerCase(): ' + lowercase);
console.log('toUpperCase(): ' + upperCase);
console.log('toTitleCase(): ' + titleCase);
```

Comment: -1 this code is very prone to errors with everything non-ASCII. For example, with the German input "die straße", you will get "Die Strasse" as the title case. Correct would be "Die Straße". Apart from that, prototype pollution is nowadays frowned upon.

Comment: @ComFreek It could've been faulty back then, but as for now, it works fairly well with `node V17` and `chrome V104`

Answer (score 13):

I paid attention that lots of people [are looking](http://www.google.com.ua/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=strtolower%20js) for `strtolower()` in JavaScript. They are expecting the same function name as in other languages, and that's why this post is here.

I would recommend using a [native](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/strings.html#tocase) JavaScript function:

`"SomE StriNg".toLowerCase()`

Here's the function that behaves exactly the same as PHP's one (for those who are porting PHP code into JavaScript)

```
function strToLower (str) {
    return String(str).toLowerCase();
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Methods or functions: toLowerCase() and toUpperCase()

Description: These methods are used to cover a string or alphabet from lowercase to uppercase or vice versa. E.g., "and" to "AND".

Converting to uppercase:

Example code:

```html
<script language=javascript>
    var ss = " testing case conversion method ";
    var result = ss.toUpperCase();
    document.write(result);
</script>
```

Result: TESTING CASE CONVERSION METHOD

Converting to lowercase:

Example Code:

```html
<script language=javascript>
    var ss = " TESTING LOWERCASE CONVERT FUNCTION ";
    var result = ss.toLowerCase();
    document.write(result);
</script>
```

Result: testing lowercase convert function

Explanation: In the above examples,

- toUpperCase() method converts any string to "UPPER" case letters.
- toLowerCase() method converts any string to "lower" case letters.

Answer (score 8):

Note that the function will *only* work on *string* objects.

For instance, I was consuming a plugin, and was confused why I was getting a "extension.tolowercase is not a function" JavaScript error.

```
 onChange: function(file, extension)
    {
      alert("extension.toLowerCase()=>" + extension.toLowerCase() + "<=");
```

Which produced the error "extension.toLowerCase is not a function". So I tried this piece of code, which revealed the problem!

```
alert("(typeof extension)=>" + (typeof extension) + "<=");;
```

The output was "(typeof extension)=>object<=" - so aha, I was *not* getting a string var for my input.  The fix is straightforward though - just force the darn thing into a String!:

```
var extension = String(extension);
```

After the cast, the *extension.toLowerCase()* function worked fine.

Answer (score 4):

**Option 1: Using [toLowerCase()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase)**

```
var x = 'ABC';
x = x.toLowerCase();
```

**Option 2: Using your own function**

```
function convertToLowerCase(str) {
  var result = '';

  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
    var code = str.charCodeAt(i);
    if (code > 64 && code < 91) {
      result += String.fromCharCode(code + 32);
    } else {
      result += str.charAt(i);
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

Call it as:

```
x = convertToLowerCase(x);
```

Comment: The first option has already been mentioned in other answers, the second option fails badly for everything non-ASCII.

Answer (score 3):

Simply use JS `toLowerCase()`
`let v = "Your Name"
 let u = v.toLowerCase();` or
`let u = "Your Name".toLowerCase();`

Answer (score 1):

Simply you can use built-in methods of javascript like toLowerCase()

```
let str=Hello World;
let lowercasestr=str.toLowerCase()
console.log("lowercasestr")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const str = 'Your Name';

// convert string to lowercase
const lowerStr = str.toLowerCase();

// print the new string
console.log(lowerStr);
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use the in built .toLowerCase() method on JavaScript strings. Example:

```
var x = "Hello";
x.toLowerCase();
```

Comment: This is identical to the accepted answer minus good code formatting

Answer (score -2):

In case you want to build it yourself:

```
function toLowerCase(string) {

    let lowerCaseString = "";

    for (let i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
        // Find ASCII charcode
        let charcode = string.charCodeAt(i);

        // If uppercase
        if (charcode > 64 && charcode < 97) {
            // Convert to lowercase
            charcode = charcode + 32
        }

        // Back to char
        let lowercase = String.fromCharCode(charcode);

        // Append
        lowerCaseString = lowerCaseString.concat(lowercase);
    }

    return lowerCaseString
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Try this short way:

```
var lower = (str+"").toLowerCase();
```

Comment: Please explain your answer. For instance, why is `+ ""` necessary? How is it different from previous answers? Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55868778/edit), not here in comments (*********** ***without*** *********** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Answer (score -4):

Try

```html
<input type="text" style="text-transform: uppercase">  <!-- uppercase -->
<input type="text" style="text-transform: lowercase">  <!-- lowercase -->
```

[Demo - JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oneofthelions/z45ygobL/)

Comment: Nice, but not especially javascriptish, no?

Comment: Building on what @some-non-descript-user said, the OP is looking for a JavaScript solution. Though this answer is valid, it does not answer the OP's question as per the defined parameters.