# Regex to check if the first character is uppercase

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to check that the first character of a username is capital, the following can be letters or numbers and at most 20 characters long.  Can someone explain why my syntax is wrong?

```
/^[A-z][a-z0-9_-]{3,19}$/
```

Comment: Please use more descriptive question titles. `:)`

Comment: Your description doesn't match your regex. According to your description, you'd want something more like this `/^[A-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]{1,19}$/`

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Your first Z is not a capital Z.

```
/^[A-Z][a-z0-9_-]{3,19}$/
```

Comment: I tried this, but for some reason the first letter isn't being recognized as capital.  I entered "ssss" and it matched.

Comment: Actually never mind, I was using a regex expression tool incorrectly.

Answer (score 10):

Why can't you let the poor users pick their own usernames? What you should do is [convert all caps to lowercase](https://stackoverflow.com/q/154862/365102).

```
"User Name".toLowerCase();
```

---

But if you are truly evil, you should change that `z` to a `Z`:

```
/^[A-Z][A-Za-z0-9_-]{3,19}$/
```

Comment: I'd say this is the perfect answer to spend my last vote on :)

Answer (score 7):

I would do it like this:

```
var firstChar = strToCheck.substring(0, 1);

if (firstChar == firstChar.toUpperCase()) {
    // it is capital :D
}
```

Comment: Anything that avoids a regex is ok in my book.

Comment: @muntoo it's just about the idea, of course you should check it :P But you could also disallow spaces, solved :P

Answer (score 6):

Your first character needs to be `A-Z`, not `A-z`

So

`/^[A-z][a-z0-9_-]{3,19}$/`

Should be

`/^[A-Z][a-z0-9_-]{3,19}$/`

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo, the first z should be a capital -

```
/^[A-Z][a-z0-9_-]{3,19}$/
```