# Can 1 TextBox have 2 RegularExpressionValidator?

Tags: asp.net, server-side-validation

I'm trying to validate a **TextBox** used for the username in the user registration page. The conditions are:

1. First character should be an uppercase letter.
2. Length should be a maximum of 8 characters.

I'm using a **RegularExpressionValidator** to check both conditions at the same time but this results in the same error message: `"Username should be maximum 8 characters long and start with an uppercase letter."`.

I would like to display specific error messages based on the above conditions, say:

- Condition 1: Username should start with an uppercase letter.
- Condition 2: Username should be maximum 8 characters long.

**I want both error messages to appear if both conditions are not satisfied.**

Here is my present code:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="username" runat="server" CssClass="InputText"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvUsername" runat="server"
    ControlToValidate="username" Display="Dynamic"
    EnableClientScript="true">Username is required
</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator
    ID="revUsername" runat="server" Display="Dynamic"  
    ControlToValidate="username"
    ValidationExpression="[A-Z][A-Z0-9]{0,7}" >
        Username should be max 8 characters long
        and should start with an alphabet.
</asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

How do I achieve this?

Comment: And having 2 separate validators attached to the same element doesn't work for you?

Comment: no it does not. I even tried adding CustomValidator for the second condition even then it does not give required output.

Comment: It works for me. I just tested it. If I submit the form leaving the username field empty I get: `Username is required`. If i enter something and submit the form, I get: `Username should be max 8 characters long and should start with an alphabet.`

Comment: sorry you got me wrong. I want to display 2 different error messages. Please read the question carefully. Hope my question is clear.

Comment: You want to **display both error messages when the username field is empty**, then. The way you phrased your question does not express this clearly.

Comment: Oh no. When condition 1 fails display: Username should start with and alphabet. When condition 2 fails display: Username should be max 8 characters.

Comment: that's exactly what I tested and it works fine (at least on my PC). What error, if any, do you get specifically? What do you see when you run the code you posted?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34634/discussion-between-hima-and-icarus)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<asp:TextBox ID="username" runat="server" MaxLength="8" CssClass="InputText"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvUsername" runat="server"
    ControlToValidate="username" Display="Dynamic"
    EnableClientScript="true">Username is required
</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

for first letter uppercase 
[Regex to check if the first character is uppercase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8274562/regex-to-check-if-the-first-character-is-uppercase)