# In what JS engines, specifically, are toLowerCase & toUpperCase locale-sensitive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unicode, internationalization, turkish

In the code of some libraries (e.g. [AngularJS](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/bb5bf7f8162d11610a53428e630b47030bdc38e5/src/Angular.js#L164), the link leads to the specific lines in the code), I can see that custom case-conversion functions are used instead of the standard ones. It's justified by an assumption that in browsers with Turkish locale, the standard functions don't work as expected:

```
console.log("SCRIPT".toLowerCase()); // "scrıpt"
console.log("script".toUpperCase()); // "SCRİPT"
```

But is it really or was it ever the case? Do the browsers really behave this way? If so, which of them do? What about node.js? Other JS engines?

The existance of the `toLocaleLowerCase` and `toLocaleUpperCase` methods implies that `toLowerCase` and `toUpperCase` are locale-invariant, doesn't it?

For what browsers, specifically, does the Angular team retain this check in the code: `if ('i' !== 'I'.toLowerCase())...`?

---

If your browser (device) uses the Turkish or Azerbaijan locale, please run this snippet and write me if you discover that the issue indeed exists.

```js
if ('i' !== 'I'.toLowerCase()) {
  document.write('Ooops! toLowerCase is locale-sensitive in your browser. ' +
    'Please write your user-agent in the comments to this question: ' +
    navigator.userAgent); 
} else {
  document.write('toLowerCase isn\'t locale-sensitive in your browser. ' +
    'Everything works as expected!');
}
```

```html
<html lang="tr">
```

Comment: A quick rule of thumb.  Anything that can be loosely defined as a "literal" (custom grammar tokens, command line arguments, string enums, etc.) should be converted with `toLowerCase`/`toUpperCase`.  Anything that can be loosely defined as "content" (forum post content, email subject, proper names, etc.) should be converted with `toLocaleLowerCase`/`toLocaleUpperCase`.

Comment: Otherwise, bad things will happen.  If you use `toLocaleLowerCase`/`toLocaleUpperCase` in your custom SQL parser then your Turkish customers will have to type `SELECT x FROM books WHERE Author LİKE '%Adams%'`.  If you use `toLowerCase`/`toUpperCase` in your content formatter then you will make typos.  Your Turkish customer will see `DIŞ` (outside) become `diş` (tooth) instead of `dış`.

Answer (score 17):

**Note**: Please, note that I couldn't test it!

---

As per [ECMAScript specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.5.4.16):

> #### String.prototype.toLowerCase ( )
>
> [...]
>
> For the purposes of this operation, the 16-bit code units of the
>   Strings are treated as code points in the Unicode Basic Multilingual
>   Plane. Surrogate code points are directly transferred from S to L
>   without any mapping.
>
> The result must be derived ***according to the case mappings in the
>   Unicode character database*** (this explicitly includes not only the
>   UnicodeData.txt file, ***but also the SpecialCasings.txt*** file that
>   accompanies it in Unicode 2.1.8 and later).
>
> [...]
>
> #### String.prototype.toLocaleLowerCase ( )
>
> This function works exactly the same as toLowerCase except that its
>   result is intended to yield the correct result for the host
>   environment’s current locale, rather than a locale-independent result.
>   There will only be a difference in the few cases (such as Turkish)
>   where the rules for that language conflict with the regular Unicode
>   case mappings.
>
> [...]

And as per [Unicode Character Database Special Casing](http://www.unicode.org/Public/UCD/latest/ucd/SpecialCasing.txt):

> [...]
>
> #### Format
>
> > The entries in this file are in the following machine-readable format:
> >
> > `<code>; <lower>; <title>; <upper>; (<condition_list>;)? # <comment>`
>
> #### Unconditional mappings
>
> [...]
>
> > Preserve canonical equivalence for I with dot. Turkic is handled
> >     below.
>
> `0130; 0069 0307; 0130; 0130; # LATIN CAPITAL LETTER I WITH DOT ABOVE`
>
> [...]
>
> > Language-Sensitive Mappings
> >     These are characters whose full case mappings depend on language and perhaps also
> >     context (which characters come before or after). For more information
> >     see the header of this file and the Unicode Standard.
>
> #### Lithuanian
>
> > Lithuanian retains the dot in a lowercase i when followed by accents.
> >
> > Remove DOT ABOVE after "i" with upper or titlecase
>
> `0307; 0307; ; ; lt After_Soft_Dotted; # COMBINING DOT ABOVE`
>
> > Introduce an explicit dot above when lowercasing capital I's and J's
> >     whenever there are more accents above.
> >     (of the accents used in Lithuanian: grave, acute, tilde above, and ogonek)
>
> `0049; 0069 0307; 0049; 0049; lt More_Above; # LATIN CAPITAL LETTER I`
>
> `004A; 006A 0307; 004A; 004A; lt More_Above; # LATIN CAPITAL LETTER J`
>
> `012E; 012F 0307; 012E; 012E; lt More_Above; # LATIN CAPITAL LETTER I WITH OGONEK`
>
> `00CC; 0069 0307 0300; 00CC; 00CC; lt; # LATIN CAPITAL LETTER I WITH GRAVE`
>
> `00CD; 0069 0307 0301; 00CD; 00CD; lt; # LATIN CAPITAL LETTER I WITH ACUTE`
>
> `0128; 0069 0307 0303; 0128; 0128; lt; #LATIN CAPITAL LETTER I WITH TILDE`
>
> #### Turkish and Azeri
>
> > I and i-dotless; I-dot and i are case pairs in Turkish and Azeri
> >     The following rules handle those cases.
>
> `0130; 0069; 0130; 0130; tr; # LATIN CAPITAL LETTER I WITH DOT ABOVE`
>
> `0130; 0069; 0130; 0130; az; # LATIN CAPITAL LETTER I WITH DOT ABOVE`
>
> > When lowercasing, remove dot_above in the sequence I + dot_above, which will turn into i.
> >     This matches the behavior of the canonically equivalent I-dot_above
>
> `0307; ; 0307; 0307; tr After_I; # COMBINING DOT ABOVE`
>
> `0307; ; 0307; 0307; az After_I; # COMBINING DOT ABOVE`
>
> > When lowercasing, unless an I is before a dot_above, it turns into a dotless i.
>
> `0049; 0131; 0049; 0049; tr Not_Before_Dot; # LATIN CAPITAL LETTER I`
>
> `0049; 0131; 0049; 0049; az Not_Before_Dot; # LATIN CAPITAL LETTER I`
>
> > When uppercasing, i turns into a dotted capital I
>
> `0069; 0069; 0130; 0130; tr; # LATIN SMALL LETTER I`
>
> `0069; 0069; 0130; 0130; az; # LATIN SMALL LETTER I`
>
> > Note: the following case is already in the UnicodeData.txt file.
> >
> > `0131; 0131; 0049; 0049; tr; # LATIN SMALL LETTER DOTLESS I`
> >
> > `EOF`

Also, as per [JavaScript for Absolute Beginners *(by Terry McNavage)*](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=wFJokhwM0rYC&pg=PA34&lpg=PA34&dq=javascript%20turkish%20dotless%20i&source=bl&ots=zhlFGFJ5Yc&sig=uNwrIN9biCn0O29NffI8wBAsDZU&hl=en&sa=X&ei=KWEMVaGyH8_dsASSqILoCA&ved=0CEYQ6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=javascript%20turkish%20dotless%20i&f=false):

> ```
> > "I".toLowerCase() // "i"
> > "i".toUpperCase() // "I"
> > "I".toLocaleLowerCase() // "<dotless-i>"
> > "i".toLocaleUpperCase() // "<dotted-I>"
> ```
>
> **Note**: `toLocaleLowerCase()` and `toLocaleUpperCase()` convert case **based on your OS settings**. You'd have to change those settings to Turkish for the previous sample to work. Or just take my word for it!

And as per [bobince's comment over *Convert JavaScript String to be all lower case?* question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1850197/1064325):

> `Accept-Language` and `navigator.language` are two completely separate
>   settings. `Accept-Language` reflects the user's chosen preferences for
>   what languages they want to receive in web pages (and this setting is
>   unfortuately inaccessible to JS). `navigator.language` merely reflects
>   which localisation of the web browser was installed, and should
>   generally not be used for anything. Both of these values are unrelated
>   to the system locale, which is the bit that decides what
>   toLocaleLowerCase() will do; **that's an OS-level setting** out of scope
>   of the browser's prefs.

---

So, setting `lang="tr-TR"` to `html` won't reflect a real test case, since it's an OS setting that's required to reproduce the special casing example.

I think that only lowercasing dotted-I or uppercasing dotless-i would be locale specific when using `toLowerCase()` or `toUpperCase()`.

As per those credible/official sources, I think you're right: `'i' !== 'I'.toLowerCase()` would always evaluate to false.

But, as I said, I couldn't test it here.

Comment: Sorry, my question is not about theory. It's about reality. There is a practical reason for those checks to exist in the code. And I'm asking: what is this reason? Would be great to hear from someone having first-hand experience of dealing with this particular problem.

Comment: @thorn Yes, my answer has theory. But it has also practice! When I point out a few *third-party* experiences such as Bobince's and Terry's (even those weren't mine) they're about reality. Well, anyway, I thought it would be someway a good contribution.

Answer (score 14):

Any JS implementations that follow ECMA-262 5.1 standard have to implement `String.prototype.toLocaleLowerCase` and `String.prototype.toLocaleUpperCase`

And as per the standard `toLocaleLowerCase` is supposed convert string to it's lower case mapping as per locale specific mapping.

Where as `toLowerCase` converts to lowercase string as defined by unicode mappings.

For most languages `toLocaleLowerCase` and `toLowerCase` give the same result. But for certain languages, like turkish the case mapping don't follow unicode mapping thus `toLowerCase` and `toLocaleLowerCase` give different result.

The Library/Framework you use (Jquery, Angular, Node whatever else) does not make any difference whatsoever. It's in what JS implementation you use to run your JS libaries that makes and changes things.

For all practical purposes it's accurate to conclude that Node/Angular or any other JS libraries and frameworks all behave exactly the same when dealing with strings (as long as they are used by JS Engine that implements ECMA-262 3 and above). Having said that, I'm sure many frameworks extend the string object to add more functionality, but the [basic properties and functions defined by ECMA-262 5.1](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) always exists and WILL behave exactly the same.

To learn more : http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.5.4.17

As far as browsers are concerned, all modern browsers implement the ECMA-262 5.1 standards in their JS engine. I am not sure about Node, but from what limited exposure I have with Node, I think they too use JS implemented per ECMA-262 5.1 standard.

Comment: Please follow my link to Angular's code. If the situation is as you describe it ('For all practical purposes it's accurate to conclude that Node/Angular or any other JS libraries and frameworks all behave exactly the same when dealing with strings'.), then why does the Angular team keep custom case-conversion functions and this check in their code: `if ('i' !== 'I'.toLowerCase())...`? As per your answer, this condition always evaluates to false.

Comment: No, the condition does not always evaluate to `false`. It will evaluate to true if `html lang='tr'` for example. All other cases, where unicode case mapping causes `'I'.toLowerCase()` to be equal to `i`; the expression is `false`. As for, why angular does not simply use `toLocaleLowerCase` ? I don't know, I am not involved with Angular development. But I'd guess, it's to make sure that the code does not break on older browsers that don't support ECMA-262 (eg: IE5)

Comment: Also, check out this page, it shows the various browser compatibility to various ECMA-262 specs as well as non-standard JS implementations. http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/

Comment: In which browsers does the `lang` attribute affect the behavior of `toLowerCase`? What is the source of this information?

Comment: Pasted the wrong link earlier. To answer your question. Basically, In all browsers that can read the `lang` attribute. http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/dirlang.html#h-8.1

Comment: Just tried it in my Chrome. It changes the way CSS converts cases (`text-transform: uppercase`), but doesn't affect JS.

Comment: What exactly did you try ? Sorry didn't understand.

Comment: `<html lang='tr'><body onload='document.body.innerHTML="i".toUpperCase()'>`

Comment: Just for info: turkish has `ı` and `i` with capital cases `I` and `İ`, respectively. Only this part differs from English or similar. All other Turkish characters has same glyph form in lower and upper cases; ç, ö, ğ, ü, ş and Ç, Ö, Ğ, Ü, Ş.