# fn instanceof RegExp

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I was staring at the angular source code (as I do from time to time) and I was surprised to see the following check:

```
if (isFunction(fn) && !(fn instanceof RegExp)) {

} else {
  // in IE, native methods are not functions so they cannot be bound (note: they don't need to be)
}
```

It's part of `angular.bind` implementation. The full snippet can be found [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/Angular.js#L1087).

This is the implementation for `isFunction` (in case you were wondering):

```
function isFunction(value) {return typeof value === 'function';}
```

Now, let me add this, just in case:

I know what `instanceof` operator does. It checks to see if a function's prototype (in this case `RegExp.prototype`) can be found on the prototype chain starting from a particular object.

Now, my question is:

Can you give me an example of a scenario where the above code will follow the else clause? I'm interested in the second part of the expression, I know you can make that condition fail by not providing a function.

That comment warns me about a weird behaviour in IE, but I cannot reproduce it.

Comment: I have a vague memory that (perhaps only in IE) a RegExp instance is callable as a function. I can't find anything about that with a few googles however.

Answer (score 1):

In IE7:

```
typeof window.item // => 'string'
```

However (in IE7):

```
window.item(0) // => [object] { onbeforeunload: null, ...}
```

In IE9:

```
typeof window.item // => 'function'
```

In IE11:

```
typeof window.item // => 'string'
```

Comment: `typeof window.item` yields "function" on IE11 (on my machine, at least). Also none of these evaluates to true when it comes to the expression `fn instanceof RegExp`

Answer (score 0):

In Netscape's original implementation, `RegExp` objects were actually functions. `re(string)` and `re.exec(string)` were supposed to mean the same thing. In the Netscape and Mozilla browsers, it was supported up through Firefox 4 (released on March 22, 2011). However, `typeof` stopped returning `"function"` for `RegExp` objects even earlier.

It's not the first time a legacy of the Dark Ages has been noticed in the code of Angular. Here is [another example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28792027). Angular 1.0.0 was released on June 13, 2012.