# Difference between toLocaleLowerCase() and toLowerCase()

Tags: javascript, html, string, localization, locale

I was trying to [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xameeramir/kr33b0aL/) with [`toLocaleLowerCase()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tolocalelowercase.asp) and [`toLowerCase()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tolowercase.asp) methods.

```js
function ByLocale() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerText.toLocaleLowerCase();
}

function ByLower() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerText.toLowerCase();
}
```

```html
<p>Click the button to convert the string "HELLO World!" to lowercase letters.</p>

  <button onclick="ByLocale();">By Locale LowerCase</button>
  <button onclick="ByLower();">By LowerCase</button>

<p id="demo">HELLO World!</p>
```

My questions are:

- What is **Locale**, because both the functions seems to return similar output?
- What is the difference between these two methods?
- Why is the fiddle code not getting executed?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/155257

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Unlike `toLowerCase`, `toLocaleLowerCase` takes localization into account. In most cases, with most languages, they will produce similar output, however certain languages will behave differently.

[Check out the description on MDN:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLocaleLowerCase)

> *The `toLocaleLowerCase()` method returns the value of the string converted to lower case according to any locale-specific case mappings. `toLocaleLowerCase()` does not affect the value of the string itself. In most cases, this will produce the same result as `toLowerCase()`, but for some locales, such as Turkish, whose case mappings do not follow the default case mappings in Unicode, there may be a different result.*

For completeness, `toUpperCase` and `toLocaleUpperCase` behave likewise, except with upper-casing.

---

Now for the issue with your snippet not doing anything. There are actually 2 issues.

1. These methods return new strings and don't modify the original (JavaScript strings are immutable). You will need to re-assign the value back to the element.
2. <s>`innerText` is non-standard, and will not work across all browsers. Use `textContent` instead, and only add `innerText` to support old versions of IE.</s> **UPDATE:** [`innerText`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/innerText) is now standardized, though it was not at the time this answer was posted.

### Working Snippet:

```js
const demo = document.getElementById('demo');
const str = demo.textContent;

function toLowerCase() {
  demo.textContent = str.toLowerCase();
}

function toLocaleLowerCase() {
  demo.textContent = str.toLocaleLowerCase();
}

function toLocaleLowerCaseDe() {
  demo.textContent = str.toLocaleLowerCase('de-DE');
}

function toUpperCase() {
  demo.textContent = str.toUpperCase();
}

function toLocaleUpperCase() {
  demo.textContent = str.toLocaleUpperCase();
}

function toLocaleUpperCaseDe() {
  demo.textContent = str.toLocaleUpperCase('de-DE');
}

function reset() {
  demo.textContent = str;
}
```

```html
<p>Click the buttons to apply each function to the string below.</p>

<button onclick="toLowerCase();">toLowerCase</button>
<button onclick="toLocaleLowerCase();">toLocaleLowerCase</button>
<button onclick="toLocaleLowerCaseDe();">toLocaleLowerCase("de-DE")</button>
<br><br>
<button onclick="toUpperCase();">toUpperCase</button>
<button onclick="toLocaleUpperCase();">toLocaleUpperCase</button>
<button onclick="toLocaleUpperCaseDe();">toLocaleUpperCase("de-DE")</button>
<br><br>
<button onclick="reset();">reset</button>

<p id="demo">WELCOME TO THE WORLD FÊTE! In HAUPTSTRAßE, İstanbul.</p>
```

Comment: And what is the bug in the [code](http://jsfiddle.net/xameeramir/kr33b0aL/) I'm trying to run

Comment: @student One second, I'll add that also.

Comment: With English, the two methods give the same output. I'd guess it is relevant with languages like French where cap letters do not take accent in Switzerland but does in France by convention.

Comment: @student Added a working snippet with explanation.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara Does it also apply to toLocaleUpperCase and [toUpperCase](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_touppercase.asp)?

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara You should have added a `turkish` word as an example to demo the difference ;-)

Comment: [`innerText` is standardized as of 2016](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#the-innertext-idl-attribute)

Comment: Added more examples to the code. My understanding is that in the `en-EN` locale, all results from the "Locale" functions would be the same as those from the "non-Locale" 
functions. If anyone can find a counter-example please comment here and/or add it to the code.