# How to make search case insensitive using nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, search

I have a search function so i have input from client `Str` if that matchs with content in file send that in response. Lets assume i have text in file `Lorem` now if i search as `lorem` from client, it sends empty array because of case sensitive. How can i make search case insensitive ?

searchService.js

```
var searchStr;
function readFile(str, logFiles, callback) {
        searchStr = str;
        // loop through each file
        async.eachSeries(logFiles, function (logfile, done) {
            // read file
            fs.readFile('logs/dit/' + logfile.filename, 'utf8', function (err, data) {
                if (err) {
                    return done(err);
                }
                var lines = data.split('\n'); // get the lines
                lines.forEach(function(line) { // for each line in lines
                    if (line.indexOf(searchStr) != -1) { // if the line contain the searchSt
                        results.push({
                        filename:logfile.filename,
                        value:line
                        });
                    }
                });
                // when you are done reading the file
                done();
            });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert JavaScript String to be all lower case?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/154862/convert-javascript-string-to-be-all-lower-case)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make use of `toLowerCase()`

```
if (line.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchStr.toLowerCase()) != -1) { ...
```

Comment: How about if we have uppercase in file content and client send lowerCase string ?

Comment: You'll notice I call `toLowerCase()` on the `line` string as well

Comment: Great! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex using .match(/pattern/i).
The /i makes the pattern search case insensitive.

`if ("LOREMMMMMM".match(/Lorem/i)) console.log("Match");`