# how to write a java script which returns the calling string value converted to lowercase. function("ABCDE"); // return "abcde"

Tags: javascript

need to write code which converts ABCDE in to abcde in java-script without using to-lowercase function.Write a function which returns the calling string value converted to
lowercase. //function("ABCDE"); // return "abcde"

Comment: `String.prototype.toLowerCase`

Comment: Post some code that you've tried. You will not get a favorable response on this site if you simply ask people to write code for you. Also, you should read "How to create a Minimum, Complete and Verifiable example". https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: And read "How do I ask a good question?" too. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: `yourStringOrVarThatIsAString.toLowerCase();`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert JavaScript String to be all lower case?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/154862/convert-javascript-string-to-be-all-lower-case)

Answer (score 1):

Really?

```js
addEventListener('load', function(){

function lame(string){
  return string.toLowerCase();
}
console.log(lame('THIS is A LaMe Function'));

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this method to convert

```
function convert(str) { 

 var result = ' ';
 for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++) { 
     var code = str.charCodeAt(i) // check if it's within the range of capital letters
      if (code > 64 && code < 91) { // if so, add a new character to the result string // of the character from our code, plus 32
       result += String.fromCharCode(code + 32) } else { // otherwise, just add the current character 
       result += str.charAt(i) } }

       return result;
       }
```

This may be helpful