# Convert letters to lowercase from an array in JS

Tags: javascript, uppercase, lowercase

I have the following code:

```
var str = "abcabcABCABC"
var chars = str.split("");
var lettersCount = {};
for (var i = 0; i < chars.length;i++)
{
    if (lettersCount[chars[i]] == undefined )
        lettersCount[chars[i]] = 0;
    lettersCount[chars[i]] ++;
}
for (var i in lettersCount)
{
    console.log(i + ' = ' + lettersCount[i]);
}
```

This code is counting how many same letters are in a word. What am I trying is to convert the uppercase letters to lowercase so it should show like this: a - 4, b -4, now it shows: a - 2, A - 2.
I've just started with Js so please be good with me. :)

Comment: [str.toLowerCase()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toLowerCase)?

Comment: try assigning a variable and using it after changing its case `let c = chars[i].toLowerCase(); if (lettersCount[c] == undefined)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just need the string to be converted into lowercase letter then you can do it like this:-

```
var str = "abcabcABCABC";
var newStr = str.toLowerCase();
console.log(newStr);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. It worked! :) It was so simple, i don't know how I didn't figure it out.

Comment: @buft Np, happy to help!! Please accept the answer, so that it can help other people as well.

Comment: For questions like those, please see if there is a duplicate first. The goal of Stack Overflow is to be a helpful resource to future visitors and [duplicates make sure that all the good and up-to-date content is in one place](https://stackoverflow.com/help/duplicates). In this case [there is already a post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154862/convert-javascript-string-to-be-all-lower-case) with 1200+ upvotes and 14 answers.

Comment: @Ivar Noted, thanks.