# The text copied with the javascript button format the text in lower case

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using a button to copy all text from an "input text area", but I need the text to be in uppercase and the script to format everything in lowercase.

How to make it uppercase?

```js
function myFunction() {
        // Get the text field
        var copyText = document.getElementById("myInput");
        // Select the text field
        copyText.select();
        copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999); // For mobile devices
        // Copy the text inside the text field
        navigator.clipboard.writeText(copyText.value);
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert JavaScript String to be all lowercase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154862/convert-javascript-string-to-be-all-lowercase)

Comment: You could have looked in the documentation :) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/toUpperCase

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this, see the edit in last line:

```js
function myFunction() {
        // Get the text field
        var copyText = document.getElementById("myInput");
        // Select the text field
        copyText.select();
        copyText.setSelectionRange(0, 99999); // For mobile devices
        // Copy the text inside the text field
        navigator.clipboard.writeText(copyText.value.toLocaleLowerCase()); // Add this
}
```

Comment: Hi, your answer may address the question; however, try to improve it adding an explanation, or a link,  so others can confirm that is a good answer (useful for the community). Read [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `.toLowerCase()` And `.toUpperCase()`functions to modify a string to be either fully lower or upper case

```
let text = "this text is fully lower case"

console.log(text.toUpperCase()) // logs: "THIS TEXT IS FULLY LOWER CASE"
```

Comment: I must confess that I'm up-voting mostly because of the entertainment value of "*THIS TEXT IS FULLY LOWER CASE*," though posting a correct answer is also useful.